# https post in C# windows form

Tags: c#, https

I need your help. I have to call post method to the https server, and I have some problems. It is like that:

for checking the url I use restclient in Firefox extension. It works and respond. But when I use the same parameters in C# Win form it don't works. In other words:

```
public static string StartReguest(string header ,string headerVal,string data )
{
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);  
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "ru");
            request.Headers.Set(header, headerVal);
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            **Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Flush();
            dataStream.Close();**


           request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml/application/xml; q=0.9,'/';q=0.8";
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
            reader.ReadLine();
            string html = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return html;
}
```

The problem is in the line which is bold, actually it is not problem  I don't get error. program works. but it don't post any  text what I wrote. At first  I want to say that uri is in https  but it works in http also  that is why I don't think that problem is with certificate. 
i guess that data stream couldnot write data . but why  ?

Comment: Try to set the Accept and KeepAlive values before sending the post data.

Comment: result is the same  .

Comment: Can you install [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and figure out the difference between what goes on the wire when using restclient and your code? Can you try to use a StreamWriter instead of that barebone stream you use?

Comment: i use stream  . but how can i use anything else instead of Stream ?  do u have any suggestions? also it works in httpReguester

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
            var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());

            streamWriter.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
```

Instead of this:

```
        **Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Flush();
        dataStream.Close();**
```

Answer (score 0):

well, I'm a little worried about how the parameters are be passing.

What do you think about passing parameters with a List or a Dictionary with UrlEncode?

For example you can do this:

`Dictionary<string,string> postParams` for string parameters.

```
string strData = "";

foreach (string key in postParams.Keys)
    {
        strData += HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key) + "="
              + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(postParameters[key]) + "&";
    }

byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strData);
```

Here works with WinForms pretty good!

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks . problmem was with certificate .  it doesn't  matter what you send .  problem was in the channel . thanks for your valuable information i also probe it like this again  .